# How to execute INSERT statement using JdbcTemplate class from Spring Framework

Tags: java, spring, jdbctemplate

In Spring, how can I insert data in table using [JdbcTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html). Can anyone please provide me a code sample for doing this.

Answer (score 99):

Use [`jdbcTemplate.update(String sql, Object... args)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#update-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) method:

```
jdbcTemplate.update(
    "INSERT INTO schema.tableName (column1, column2) VALUES (?, ?)",
    var1, var2
);
```

or [`jdbcTemplate.update(String sql, Object[] args, int[] argTypes)`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#update-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object:A-int:A-), if you need to map arguments to SQL types manually:

```
jdbcTemplate.update(
    "INSERT INTO schema.tableName (column1, column2) VALUES (?, ?)",
    new Object[]{var1, var2}, new Object[]{Types.TYPE_OF_VAR1, Types.TYPE_OF_VAR2}
);
```

Comment: Note that there (now ?) is an overload that accepts varargs, so you don't need to create a new array anymore.

Comment: @PieterDeBie But sometimes you may need to map parameter types to SQL types manually :)

Comment: Ah yes, my bad. I didn't see the Types array.

Answer (score 16):

If you are planning to use JdbcTemplate in multiple locations, it would be a good idea to create a Spring Bean for it.

Using Java Config it would be:

```
@Configuration
public class DBConfig {

   @Bean
   public DataSource dataSource() {
      //create a data source
   }

   @Bean
   public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate() {
      return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource());
   }

   @Bean
   public TransactionManager transactionManager() {
      return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource());
   }

}
```

Then a repository that uses that JdbcTemplate could be:

```
@Repository
public class JdbcSomeRepository implements SomeRepository {

   private final JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate ;

   @Autowired
   public JdbcSomeRepository(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
      this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
   } 

   @Override
   @Transactional 
   public int someUpdate(SomeType someValue, SomeOtherType someOtherValue) {
      return jdbcTemplate.update("INSERT INTO SomeTable(column1, column2) VALUES(?,?)", someValue, someOtherValue)
   }
}
```

The update method from JdbcTemplate that I have used can be found [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#update-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-).

Comment: how to make generic config so I can use read and write operation: like readJdbcTemplate and writeJdbcTemplate,

Answer (score 12):

You can alternatively use [`NamedParameterJdbcTemplate`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/namedparam/NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.html) (naming can be useful when you have many parameters)

```
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("var1",value1); 
params.put("var2",value2); 
namedJdbcTemplate.update(
    "INSERT INTO schema.tableName (column1, column2) VALUES (:var1, :var2)",
    params
);
```

Answer (score 4):

If you use spring-boot, you don't need to create a DataSource class, just specify the data url/username/password/driver in `application.properties`, then you can simply `@Autowired` it.

```
@Repository
public class JdbcRepository {

    private final JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public DynamicRepository(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
    }

    public void insert() {
        jdbcTemplate.update("INSERT INTO BOOK (name, description) VALUES ('book name', 'book description')");
    }
}
```

Example of `application.properties`:

```
#Basic Spring Boot Config for Oracle
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=YourHostIP)(PORT=YourPort))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=dedicated)(SERVICE_NAME=YourServiceName)))
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver

#hibernate config
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
```

Then add the driver and connection pool dependencies in `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
    <version>12.1.0.1</version>
</dependency>

<!-- HikariCP connection pool -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
    <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

See the [official doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html#boot-features-using-jdbc-template) for more details.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need a `datasource` for working with `JdbcTemplate`.

```
JdbcTemplate template = new JdbcTemplate(yourDataSource);

template.update(
    new PreparedStatementCreator() {
        public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(Connection connection)
            throws SQLException {

            PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(ourInsertQuery);
            //statement.setLong(1, beginning); set parameters you need in your insert

            return statement;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score -14):

we can use update for both insert and update/delte

[image]

[image: enter link description here]