# oracle sql date errors

Tags: java, sql, oracle, spring-batch

I need your help!

I have a sql query that is executed within a jdbcTemplate like shown here :

```
public String Insertquery(FichierEclate e) {
            String var="(null)";
            String tableName="TF02_HISTO_"+Country;
            String sql = "INSERT INTO " + tableName + " (TF02TFID, TF02STID, TF02DATE, TF02UID) VALUES (" + e.getAffaireID() + ", 4, TO_TIMESTAMP('" +e.getDate()+ "','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')," + var +")";
            return sql;
        }
```

Then i just make a call :

```
String Inquery=Insertquery(item);

 vJdbcTemplate.execute(Inquery);
```

I made the same steps for a Update query and it works perfectly fine!! BUt in Insert query, it shows this error :

```
 StatementCallback; SQL [INSERT INTO TF02_HISTO_MN (TF02TFID, TF02STID, TF02DATE, TF02UID) VALUES (25472563, 4, TO_TIMESTAMP('2021-03-01 00:45:00.0','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'),(null))]; ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string
; nested exception is java.sql.SQLDataException: ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string
```

I think i don't need TO_TIMESTAMP or TO_DATE because jdbcTemplate makes the conversion automatically!!
When i removed TO_TIMESTAMP, i get error of type :

```
missing comma
```

What to do !!!!
By the way  this object : **FichierEclate e** is using a property "date" of type timestamp and i am using oracle ! here is the format example of date written in my database:

```
2021-03-01 00:45:00
```

What to do ?!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: "What to do?" Use bind variables; do not build queries using string concatenation.

Comment: In addition to said by @MT0 to avoid sql injection, why don't you convert to string your `e.getDate()` variable and see how it's formatted?

Comment: I'll echo @MT0, please use bind variables.  For the specific error you're getting, however, notice that the string you're passing to `to_timestamp` has a single digit of fractional seconds.  If you really really want to avoid using bind variables, you'd need to ensure that the format mask you're using matches the string you're converting.

Comment: @MTO your answer was the solution! Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23888778/1509264), use bind variables:

```java
vJdbcTemplate.update(
  "INSERT INTO TF02_HISTO_" + country
    + " ( TF02TFID, TF02STID, TF02DATE, TF02UID ) VALUES ( ?, 4, ?, null )",
  item.getAffaireID(), item.getDate()
);
```

Answer (score 0):

This was the solution ! thank you all for help :)

```
vJdbcTemplate.update(
  "INSERT INTO TF02_HISTO_" + country
    + " ( TF02TFID, TF02STID, TF02DATE, TF02UID ) VALUES ( ?, 4, ?, null )",
  item.getAffaireID(), item.getDate()
);
```