# jdbcTemplate query with 5 parameters for insert

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am building a Spring application and in my Repository I have to insert an sql query that has 5 parameters and I tried jdbcTemplate.query or queryForList or Map but it gives me error.

Here is the code:

```
@Repository
public class BilantErrRepository {
    
    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSourceMail;
    
    public List<BilantErr> search() {
        
        List<BilantErr> info1 = new ArrayList<>();
        BilantErr bilant = new BilantErr();
        
        JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(this.dataSourceMail);
        String sql = "INSERT into Aaa (cui,an, data_autorizare,operator,motivatie, tip_perioada) VALUES (?,?,sysdate,?,?,?)";
        info1 = jdbcTemplate.query(sql, bilant.getCui(),bilant.getAn(),bilant.getOperator(),bilant.getOperator(),bilant.getPerioada());
        
        
        return info1;
    }

}
```

What method can I use to do this insert ? Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to execute INSERT statement using JdbcTemplate class from Spring Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5026943/how-to-execute-insert-statement-using-jdbctemplate-class-from-spring-framework)

Answer (score 0):

Use [jdbcTemplate.update(String sql, Object... args)](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#update-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) method:

```
jdbcTemplate.update(
    "INSERT INTO schema.tableName (column1, column2) VALUES (?, ?)",
    var1, var2
);
```

or [jdbcTemplate.update(String sql, Object[] args, int[] argTypes)](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#update-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object:A-int:A-), if you need to map arguments to SQL types manually:

```
jdbcTemplate.update(
    "INSERT INTO schema.tableName (column1, column2) VALUES (?, ?)",
    new Object[]{var1, var2}, new Object[]{Types.TYPE_OF_VAR1, Types.TYPE_OF_VAR2}
);
```